# Hiding the api key from URL using Python

Tags: python, api, key

I am looking for a way to hide the API key from browser. When you hover over the button link you see `httpv://xyz.com/87676878796/?api_key=8698686`

I dont want the api keys to be visible .Is there any way to do this in python

Comment: Are you using django framework ? If yes, you could use this: https://django-unfriendly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to obfuscate the get params.

Comment: You can pass the API_KEY as a header instead of a get param. If your requirements allow that.